# Linux script trying to remove the 'return' in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a pretty basic script in Linux shell but I'm still learning.  Basically, everything is good to go except one part.  I direct two outputs into the same file, e.g.:

```
echo `losetup -a` > partitionfile
echo "p1" >> partition final
```

Basically, I need to add the letter/number "p1" to the end of whatever is written in the file.

The problem is, it ends up being read (cat partitionfile) as:

```
/dev/loop0
p1
```

I need it on the same line to it reads out as:

```
/dev/loop0p1
```

There has to be a way to fix this, I just don't know it.  Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: See @paxdiablo's answer. For reference, you could use `echo -n ...` in the first command to avoid writing the line feed, thereby causing the next echo to continue the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `-n` flag to the first echo statement to not print the trailing new line.

Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! This was the easiest way to fix this, but I learned something thanks to paxdiablo, too.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
echo "$(losetup -a)p1" > partitionfile
```

For an example, see the following transcript:

```
pax> echo "$(echo xyzzy_)p1"
xyzzy_p1
```

The `xyzzy_` is the output of the inner `echo` command (which in your case would be `losetup`) and the outer `echo` command appends `p1`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Actually the correct option of echo to achieve this is "\c"

> \c Keeps the cursor on the same line.

However you cannot use \c unless you have enabled it with

> -e

Thus your code should be something like this ...

```
echo -e "`losetup -a` \c" > partitionfile
echo "p1" >> partition final
```

this will write in partitionfile as

> < output of losetup -a > p1

everything on same line.